# jQuery UI 1.8.17 dialog options not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using dialog plugin from jQuery UI 1.8.17. The following code works and opens the dialog properly. But setting any option on dialog dosen't work and makes the dialog transparent. 
This happens only in IE9

```
jQuery('#faxdirectory_dialog').dialog().dialog("open");
jQuery('#faxdirectory_dialog').dialog("option", "height", 500); // this doesn't work.
```

Comment: Try specifying `'500px'` and not `500`

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried it and it didn't work. In fact the issue is not only with height option but all. If I set any option it dosen't work and makes the dialog transparent.

Comment: Ran it without any issues in IE9 with same jquery ui version: http://jsfiddle.net/E9zFw/

Comment: May be you are right, I am going to try this in a small test web app, to see if something else in my main application source code is causing it to behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using jQuery 1.4.2; we recently upgraded to 1.7.1 that seems to have fixed it. But the problem most certainly was not that, we have whole bunch of other jQuery plugins and the way they work with each other might be an issue. 
Will update the answer when I can pin point exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting height option on opening:

```
$('#faxdirectory_dialog').dialog({
   height:500
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that but that was my original code and it didn't work, so I simplified it to above code; because I thought that something is going wrong while initializing with options.